# DocumentDirectory not working in CentOS

Tags: apache, centos

I recently had to change from var/www/html to home/www. But my problem is that it won't change. If I am entering my website, only "apache 2 test page" appear and I am not able to navigate to any of my folders on the server. I will include my httpd.conf file here.

**Things I tried**

- Turn off IPtables
- Give apache ownership for the folders
- 777 permission

I am also restarting httpd after every try.

http://pastebin.com/vPuiD96L

Comment: Have you checked the sites-available folder and changed the default domain folder (virtual host)?

Comment: @Hardy not sure, I only have one website on the server.